# Entity doesn't merged to DB

Tags: spring, jpa

I have 2 simple classes. Firstly, these are the fibers that I put in the second class of the Cable.
First class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="fiberTable")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Fiber{

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.Persist)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cable_id)
    private Cable cable;

    @Column
    private Integer value;
}
```

This is the second class Cable, which contains a list of fibers.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="cableTable")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cable{

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cable")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SubSelect)
    private List<Fiber> fibers;
}
```

I'm trying to create new fiber with existing cable with this method:

class1:

```java
@Transactional
public void run(){
    // get cable from DB (cable = "cableFromDB")
    class2.proccess(cableFromDb);
}
```

class2:

```java
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) // if im not create a new transaction - I'm get the LazyInitialization exception
public void proccess(Cable cableFromDB){
    //get Fiber from list of fibers from cableFromDB with max "value" (fiber = "lastFiber")
    fiberRepository.save(Fiber.builder()
        .cable(lastFiber.getCable())
        .value(++lastFiber.getValue())
        .build());
}
```

and after I ran this code and checked my DB, I didn't see any new entries in the fiber_table

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check if there are SQL statements executed?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding MERGE as a cascade operation:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="fiberTable")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Fiber{

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "cable_id)
    private Cable cable;

    @Column
    private Integer value;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me
If I'm set only CascadeType.MERGE, without CascadeType.PERSIST - thats work for me. But other functionality is going wrong

Comment: Let me check if I understood it correctly. With `@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })` it does not work, but with `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` it does?

Comment: yes, you right. Bit im already fixed this

Comment: Do you mean you have a solution already? If yes, consider adding it as an answer so that others can benefit from it. Thanks